# Using report viewer in .net 7

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor, reportviewer

I am new to .NET Core and need to migrate a reporting code from ASP.NET MVC 5 to ASP.NET Core, but I don't know what to do. I searched for hovers but not good result so please if any one help me it will be you mercy.

Here is my controller code:

```
public ActionResult UnitByLtoMtoSto()
{
    List<SelectListItem> Provinces = new List<SelectListItem>();
        
    var provincelist = db.Provinces.Select(i => new { i.ProvinceEng,i.ProvinceCode}).ToList();

    foreach (var province in provincelist)
    {
        Provinces.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = province.ProvinceCode, Text = " " + province.ProvinceEng + " " });
    }

    ViewBag.Provinces = Provinces;
    ViewBag.Year = DateHelper.GetYearsForDropDownList(_configuration);
    ViewBag.Month = DateHelper.GetMonthsForDropDownList();

    ReportViewer reportViewer = new ReportViewer();
    reportViewer.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local;
    reportViewer.SizeToReportContent = true;
    reportViewer.Width = Unit.Percentage(100);
    reportViewer.Height = Unit.Percentage(100);
    reportViewer.ShowPrintButton = true;

    ViewBag.ReportViewer = reportViewer;

    return View();
}
```

The `ReportViwer` class does not exist in .NET Core, so if there is any alternative to do this work for me.

Here is my view:

```
    @using ReportViewerForMvc;
    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "UnitByLtoMtoSto";
    }
@using NewRMIS.LanguageResources;
@using ReportViewerForMvc;
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "UnitByLtoMtoSto";
}

<link href="~/AdminRTE/plugins/select2/select2.css" rel="stylesheet" />



<div class="portlet light bordered">
    @using (Html.BeginForm("UnitByLtoMtoSto", "collectionAgencyReports", FormMethod.Post))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        <div class="form-horizontal">
            <div class="box box-primary">
                <div class="box-header with-border text-center">
                    <h3 class="box-title">Report By LTO, MTO and STO</h3>
                    <div class="box-tools pull-right" style="display:none;">
                        <button class="btn btn-xs btn-info btn-flat margin-r-5 bg-light-blue" data-chart-role="toggle-chart" data-chart-period="year" id="changetotable">Table</button>
                        <button class="btn btn-xs btn-info btn-flat margin-r-5" data-chart-role="toggle-chart" data-chart-period="month" id="changetochart">Chart</button>

                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="inbox-content">

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-8">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-md-5 control-label">@LanResources.SelectYear</label>
                                <div class="col-md-7">
                                    @Html.DropDownList("Year", new SelectList(ViewBag.Year, "Value", "Text"), "Select an Option", new { @class = "form-control input-sm", @required = "required", @Multiple = "Multiple" })

                                    <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                                        <input type="checkbox" value="check all years" id="checkallyears" class="checkallyears" />
                                        <label class="custom-control-label" for="checkallyears">Select All Years</label>
                                    </div>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-8">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-md-5 control-label">@LanResources.SelectMonth</label>
                                <div class="col-md-7">
                                    @Html.DropDownList("Month", new SelectList(ViewBag.Month, "Value", "Text"), "Select an Option", new { @class = "form-control input-sm", @Multiple = "Multiple" })
                                    <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                                        <input type="checkbox" value="check all months" id="checkallmonths" class="checkallmonths" />
                                        <label class="custom-control-label" for="checkallmonths">Select All Months</label>
                                    </div>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-8">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-md-5 control-label">Select Provinces</label>
                                <div class="col-md-7">
                                    @Html.DropDownList("Provinces", new SelectList(ViewBag.Provinces, "Value", "Text"), "Select an Option", new { @class = "form-control input-sm", @required = "required", @Multiple = "Multiple" })

                                    <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                                        <input type="checkbox" value="check all months" id="checkallprovinces" class="checkallprovinces" />
                                        <label class="custom-control-label" for="checkallprovinces">Select All Provinces</label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-8">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-md-5 control-label">Target Type</label>
                                <div class="col-md-7">
                                    <select class="form-control input-sm" name="Targett" required="required">
                                        <option selected="selected" value="1">ARD</option>
                                        <option value="2">IMF</option>

                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-8">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-md-5 control-label">Select Format</label>
                                <div class="col-md-7">
                                    <select class="form-control input-sm" name="DocFormat" required="required">
                                        <option selected="selected" value="PDF">PDF</option>
                                        <option value="xls">Excel</option>
                                        <option value="doc">Word</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-8">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-md-7 control-label">&nbsp;</label>
                                <div class="col-md-5">
                                    <button type="submit" id="btnreport" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-print"></i>Generate Report</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row" style="position: relative;">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <div class="box box-primary">
                                <div class="box-header with-border">
                                    @*<h4>Generated Report is here!</h4>*@
                                </div>
                                <div class="box-body">
                                    <center> @Html.ReportViewer(ViewBag.ReportViewer as Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportViewer) </center>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>



                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
</div>




@section Scripts{
    <script src="~/AdminRTE/plugins/select2/select2.full.min.js"></script>
    <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('select').select2({
                    placeholder: "Select an Option",
                    allowClear: true,
                    closeOnSelect: false
                });

        });
        $(document.body).on("click", ".checkallyears", function () {

            if ($(this).prop("checked") == true) {
                $('select').eq(0).select2('destroy').find('option').prop('selected', 'selected').end().select2();
                $('select').eq(0).select2('destroy').find('option:first').prop('selected', false).end().select2();
            }
            else {
                $('select').eq(0).select2('destroy').find('option').prop('selected', false).end().select2();
            }

        });
        $(document.body).on("click", ".checkallmonths", function () {

            if ($(this).prop("checked") == true) {
                $('select').eq(1).select2('destroy').find('option').prop('selected', 'selected').end().select2();
                $('select').eq(1).select2('destroy').find('option:first').prop('selected', false).end().select2();
            }
            else {
                $('select').eq(1).select2('destroy').find('option').prop('selected', false).end().select2();
            }

        });
        $(document.body).on("click", ".checkallprovinces", function () {

            if ($(this).prop("checked") == true) {
                $('select').eq(2).select2('destroy').find('option').prop('selected', 'selected').end().select2();
                $('select').eq(2).select2('destroy').find('option:first').prop('selected', false).end().select2();
            }
            else {
                $('select').eq(2).select2('destroy').find('option').prop('selected', false).end().select2();
            }

        });
    </script>
}
```

Comment: https://www.nuget.org/packages/ReportViewerCore.NETCore/ ?

Comment: Could you please share details of `ReportViewerForMvc`? So that it can be investigated.